# C++ Exception Handling for Area of Shapes

Tags: c++, exception, event-handling, shapes, area

I am to create two custom exception classes that inherit from std::exception to handle invalid dimensions for shapes (such as 0 and negative numbers). Revise the code in the program's classes and main() to use these custom exception classes.

Below are the codes I had for the three shapes, plus the exceptions I wrote at the very bottom. When I enter invalid dimensions for the shapes, the program did not handle the exception. I am not too familiar with exceptions. Are there codes I need to add somewhere? Thank you in advance.

//Shape.h

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H_INCLUDED    
#define SHAPE_H_INCLUDED   


class Shape{    
public:    
    virtual double getArea()    
    {   };    
};
  

#endif // SHAPE_H_INCLUDED
```

//Square.h

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H_INCLUDED    
#define SQUARE_H_INCLUDED  



class Square    
{    
private:    
  int length;
  

public:    
  Square(int len);    
  int getLength()const;    
  void setLength(int len);    
  int getArea() const;      

};
```

//Circle.h

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H_INCLUDED    
#define CIRCLE_H_INCLUDED   

 
class Circle{  


private:    
  double radius, area;  


public:    
  Circle(double radius =0);    
  double getRadius()const;    
  void setRadius(double radius);    
  double getArea()const;  


};
```

//Rectangle.h

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED    
#define RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED  


using namespace std;


class Rectangle {  


private:    
  double length;    
  double width;   


public:    
  Rectangle (double length =0, double width =0);    
  double getLength();    
  double getWidth();    
  void setLength(double length);    
  void setWidth(double width);    
  double getArea ();    
};
```

//main.cpp

```
#endif // CIRCLE_H_INCLUDED    
#endif // SQUARE_H_INCLUDED    
#endif // RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED  


#include <iostream>    
#include "Circle.h"    
#include "Square.h"    
#include "Rectangle.h"  


using namespace std;  


int main()    
{    
  //declaring variables with default values

  double radius = 0;    
  int length = 0;    
  int width = 0;    
  Square square(0);    
  Circle circle(0);    
  Rectangle rectangle(0,0);

  int ch = 1;

    //switch statement to test the variables against the values

    //of the circle, square, and rectangle

    switch(ch)    
    {//start of thew while loop    
      while (ch == 1 || ch == 2) {    
        //case 1 for the value of the radius    
        case 1:    
        {    
          cout << "\nEnter radius of the circle: ";    
          cin >> radius;    
          circle.setRadius(radius);//radius is set for a circle    
          cout << "\nThe Area of the circle is "<< circle.getArea()<<endl;    
        }

        //case 2 for the value of the length

        case 2:    
        {    
          cout << "\nPlease Enter the length of the Square's side: ";    
          cin >> length;    
          square.setLength(length);//length of square is set    
          cout << "\nThe Area of the square is "<< square.getArea()<<endl;    
        }

        {

        // case 3 for the length and width of a rectangle

        case 3:    
          cout << "\nPlease Enter the length of the rectangle's length: ";    
          cin >> length;    
          cout << "\nPlease Enter the length of the rectangle's width: ";    
          cin >> width;            
          rectangle.setLength(length);    
          rectangle.setWidth(width);   


          cout << "\nThe Area of the rectangle is "<< rectangle.getArea() << endl;      

        }    
        return 0;    
        }    
    }    
}
```

//circle.cpp

```
#include <cmath>    
#include <iostream>    
#include "Circle.h"   


using namespace std;

//function to find area of a circle

Circle::Circle(double r){    
  radius = r;    
  }    
double Circle::getRadius()const{    
  return radius;    
  }    
void Circle::setRadius (double r){    
  radius = r;    
  }    
double Circle::getArea() const{    
  return (radius * radius * 3.1415926);    
 }
```

//square.cpp

```
#include "Square.h"  


using namespace std;

//function to find area of a square

Square::Square(int len){    
  length = len;    
  }    
int Square::getLength()const{    
  return length;    
  }    
void Square::setLength(int len){    
  length = len;    
  }    
int Square::getArea() const{    
  return length * length;    
  }
```

//rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

//function to find length of a rectangle

using namespace std;    


Rectangle :: Rectangle(double len, double wid){    
  length = len;    
  width = wid;    
}

double Rectangle :: getLength(){    
  return length;    
}

double Rectangle :: getWidth(){    
  return width;    
}

void Rectangle :: setLength(double len){    
  length = len;    
}    
void Rectangle :: setWidth(double wid){    
  width = wid;

  }    
double Rectangle :: getArea(){    
  return length * width;    
}
```

//Exception.cpp

```
#include "Exception1.h"


const char* Exception1::what() const throw()    
{    
  return "Invalid value";    
}
```

//Exception.h

```
#ifndef EXCEPTION1_H    
#define EXCEPTION1_H    
#include<exception>


class Exception1 : public std::exception    
{    
  public:    
  virtual const char* what() const throw();    
};

#endif /* Exception1_H */
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Where in your code are you throwing any exceptions for them to be handled?

Comment: I don’t see you throwing any exceptions anywhere. How would the compiler know what you want if you don’t tell it? There’s a lot of material on exceptions and their use available you can read

Comment: That's a lot of code. Read about the [mcve].

Comment: It seems you missed the part of the instructions that says "Revise the code in the program's classes and main() to use these custom exception classes."